# Code jumps straight into validator and breaks everything

Tags: angular, validation, customvalidator

I've writtten my own validators to check the input fields of my reactive form but they don't seem to work. The first two don't ever produce an error and the last one breaks everything once i add it to my code. With augury I've been debugging the best I can and I found out that with my validatePasswords, he immediately jumps into the method whilst I havn't even touched anything. If any of you can figure out why it does this or why my other validators don't ever produce an error, that would be amazing!

#### My 3 custom validators

```
function validateEmail(control: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } {
  var mailReg = /^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_éèàùäëïöüâêîôû]*)@([a-z]+)[.]([a-z]+)([.][a-z]+)*$/g;
  if (!mailReg.test(control.get('email').value)) {
    return { noValidEmail: true };
  }
  return null;
}
function validatePhone(control: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } {
  var phoneReg = /^0{0,2}(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{7,14}$/;
  if (!phoneReg.test(control.get('phone').value)) {
    return { noValidPhone: true };
  }
  return null;
}

function validatePassword(control: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } {
  if (
    control.get('password').value !== control.get('passwordConfirmation').value
  ) {
    return { noMatchingPasswords: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

#### my constructor and form:

```
 public register: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RegisterFormComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.register = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)],
        validateEmail
      ],
      phone: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)],
        validatePhone
      ],
      country: [''],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      passwordConfirmation: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), validatePassword]
      ]
    });
  }
```

#### my error message method

```
  getErrorMessage(errors: any) {
    if (errors.required) {
      return 'is required';
    } else if (errors.noValidEmail) {
      return 'not a valid email';
    } else if (errors.noValidPhone) {
      return 'no valid phone number';
    } else if (errors.noMatchingPasswords) {
      return 'passwords don\'t match';
    } else if (errors.minlength) {
      return `need at least ${errors.minlength.requiredLength} characters`;
    }
  }
```

#### the error it produces:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5280)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22085)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23353)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23315)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23949)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23909)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterFormComponent.html:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23901)
```

#### lastly, my form in html

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>Register</h3>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form [formGroup]="register" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="First name" placeholder="First name" type="text" formControlName="firstName"
        class="browser-default" required />
      <mat-error *ngIf="register.get('firstName')['errors'] && register.get('firstName').touched">
        {{ getErrorMessage(register.get('firstName')['errors']) }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="Last name" placeholder="Last name" type="text" formControlName="lastName"
        class="browser-default" required />
      <mat-error *ngIf="register.get('lastName')['errors'] && register.get('lastName').touched">
        {{ getErrorMessage(register.get('lastName')['errors']) }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="Email" placeholder="Email" type="text" formControlName="email" class="browser-default"
        required />
      <mat-error *ngIf="register.get('email')['errors'] && register.get('email').touched">
        {{ getErrorMessage(register.get('email')['errors']) }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="Phone" placeholder="Phone" type="text" formControlName="phone" class="browser-default"
        required />
      <mat-error *ngIf="register.get('phone')['errors'] && register.get('phone').touched">
        {{ getErrorMessage(register.get('phone')['errors']) }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="Country" placeholder="Country" type="text" formControlName="country"
        class="browser-default" />
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password"
        class="browser-default" required />
      <mat-error *ngIf="register.get('password')['errors'] && register.get('password').touched">
        {{ getErrorMessage(register.get('password')['errors']) }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput aria-label="Confirmation Password" placeholder="Confirmation Password" type="password"
        formControlName="passwordConfirmation" class="browser-default" required />
      <mat-error *ngIf="register.get('passwordConfirmation')['errors'] && register.get('passwordConfirmation').touched">
        {{ getErrorMessage(register.get('passwordConfirmation')['errors']) }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="buttonDiv">
      <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="!register.valid">Register</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

#### Update:

these errors are new but get now thrown as well:

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
    at Function.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.ReactiveErrors.missingFormException (forms.js:1443)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective._checkFormPresent (forms.js:5414)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5237)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22085)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23353)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23315)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23949)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23909)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterFormComponent.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23901)
```

and

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at validatePassword (register-form.component.ts:29)
    at forms.js:658
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:658)
    at FormControl.validator (forms.js:623)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.js:2914)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2890)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:3241)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder.control (forms.js:6462)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:6502)
```

(line 29 is this: `control.get('password').value !== control.get('passwordConfirmation').value`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `validatePassword` custom validator involves [cross-field validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation) (validation across multiple fields - FormControls `password` and `passwordConfirmation`), you should be passing that validator in the second argument of the initialisation of the `register` form.

You can keep the other FormControls as they are. Remove `validatePassword` from passwordConfirmation, and add it to the second argument of the formBuilder.

```
this.register = this.fb.group({
  .
  .
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
  passwordConfirmation: [
    '',
    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]
  ]
}, { validators: validatePassword });
```

---

As for your second issue, it is because the `register` FormGroup is undefined when the page is rendered. You should move it to your constructor, or simply initialise the FormControls when you declare the 'register' property on your class.

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RegisterFormComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.register = fb.group({ 
      .
      .
      // your FormControls
      .
    });
  }
```

Or

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  public register: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ 
   .
   .
   // your FormControls
   .
  })
```

Comment: So, I've done what you said, but the wouldn't work so I improvised a bit and put every validator in the `{ validators : [validatePassword, validatePhone, validateEmail ]}` The validations wroks but the messages still won't show. How come?

Comment: Ah, glad to hear that part is working. Hmm.. No error message huh? You must be referring to `getErrorMessage()`? That is probably because you might need to pass in the `error` property from the `register` FormGroup, instead of the error property from each individual FormControl. Then, on your template, you should do something like  `{{ getErrorMessage(register.errors) }}`. You get what I am trying to say? :)

Comment: Well that fixes part of it, now's the problem that it checks this with every field (name gets a invalid phone error) but I think this is fixable with placing this line only by those that have extra validation

Update: I've done this, and we're one step closer again, now the problem I'm having is that it shows the wrong error at those fields, everything gets an invalid email error